# Tweens being ignored LibGDX

Tags: java, animation, libgdx, tween

The tweens in my GameRenderer class are not working. They don't show an error, but they're just being ignored.

```
TweenManager tweenManager;
public class GameRenderer(GameWorld g){
...
tweenManager = new TweenManager();
initButton();
}
void initButton(){
.. initializing button ..
button.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
            Tween.registerAccessor(ShapeRenderer.class, new ShapeAccessor());
            Tween.set(fader, ShapeAccessor.ALPHA).target(fader.getColor().a).start(tweenManager);
            Tween.to(fader, ShapeAccessor.ALPHA, 2).target(1).start(tweenManager);
            Tween.registerAccessor(Music.class, new MusicAccessor());
            Tween.set(crowd, MusicAccessor.VOLUME).cast(Music.class).target(1).start(tweenManager);
            Tween.to(crowd, MusicAccessor.VOLUME, 2).cast(Music.class).target(0).setCallback(new TweenCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onEvent(int arg0, BaseTween<?> arg1) {
                    ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new GameScreen());
                }
            }).start(tManager);
        }
    });
}
```

when i click the button it is registered as clicked, but the tweens are being ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are updating your tween manager in your render() method like so:

tweenManager.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

Comment: @Roberisha Can you please explain how your `MusicAccessor` implemented the `Music` interface??

Comment: @WeirdElfB0y I am sorry, I am no longer in possession of this project.